# Flink: Implementing a "join" between a DataStream and a "set of rules"

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

What is the best practice recommendation for the following use case? We need to match a stream against a set of “rules”, which are essentially a Flink DataSet concept. Updates to this “rules set" are possible but not frequent. Each stream event must checked against *all* the records in “rules set”, and each match produces one or more events into a sink data stream. Number of records in a rule set are in the 6 digit range.

Currently we're simply loading rules into a local List of rules and using flatMap over an incoming DataStream. Inside flatMap, we're just iterating over a list comparing each event to each rule.

To speed up the iteration, we can also  split the list into several batches, essentially creating a list of lists, and creating a separate thread to iterate over each sub-list (using Futures in either Java or Scala).

Questions:

1. Is there a better way to do this kind of a join?
2. If not, is it safe to add additional parallelism by creating new threads inside each flatMap operation, on top of what Flink is already doing?

EDIT:
Here's sample code as requested:

```
package wikiedits

import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.wikiedits.{WikipediaEditEvent, WikipediaEditsSource}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.extensions._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

object WikipediaEditEventProcessor {

  def main(args: Array[String])= {
    val see = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val edits = see.addSource(new WikipediaEditsSource())

    val ruleSets = Map[Int, List[String]](
      (1, List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")),
      (2, List("k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t")),
      (3, List("u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3"))
    )

    val result = edits.flatMap { edit =>
      ruleSets.map { ruleSet =>
        applyRuleSet(edit, ruleSet._2, ruleSet._1)
      }
    }
    see.execute
  }

  def applyRuleSet(event: WikipediaEditEvent, ruleSet: List[String], ruleSetId: Int): Future[List[String]] = {
    val title = event.getTitle
    Future(
      ruleSet.map {
        case rule if title.contains(rule) =>
          val result = s"Ruleset $ruleSetId: $rule -> exists in: $title"
          println(result) // this would be creating an output event instead
          result
        case rule =>
          val result = s"Ruleset $ruleSetId: $rule -> NO MATCH in: $title"
          println(result)
          result
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share one simplified example of your DataSet tuple and an simplified example of Rule?

Comment: @YogiDevendra  I'm not using DataSet right now, just a simple Map or List. I posted above the full simplified example, modified from their Wikipedia example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each stream event must checked against all the records in “rules set”,
>   and each match produces one or more events into a sink data stream.
>   Number of records in a rule set are in the 6 digit range

Say you have K rules. Your approach is fine if input rate is faster than the time taken for processing K rules for single event.
Else, you need some approach where you can process these K rules in parallel.

Think of them as K toll-booth. Place them one after other rather than having them inside single big room. This would simplify the things for streaming engine.

In other words, use simple for loop to iterate over all the rules and have a separate flatMap for each rule. 
So that, each one of them is independent of each other thus can be processed in parallel. 
In the end you would have K flatMaps for execution. Engine would use maximum parallelism possible with whatever configuration you provide for execution. 
This approach limits maximum possible parallelism to K. But, that is good enough for high number of rules.

> additional parallelism by creating new threads inside each flatMap
>   operation

Not at all recommended. Leave parallelism to flink. You define unit of work you wish to perform inside your flatMap.

Comment: Yes, that is inside flatMap, I posted an example using a Future.